# Convert BNB Beacon Chain address to BNB Smart Chain address

Tags: blockchain, cryptocurrency, bsc

Example BNB Smart Chain address: `0x77b177aD227d2D6F395C7b6A8e19dDF34b2dd208`

Example BNB Beacon Chain address: `bnb1fpdn8pnwl3ft39vj7vgyez44y0u4l0d7yearnd`

They are generated with the same private key.

Imagine I have `0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` BNB Smart Chain address

How do I generate BNB Beacon Chain address?

There must be some way of doing it, since there's this TokenHub (at `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001004`) which allows to transfer tokens to Beacon Chain with `transferOut` function and WITHOUT knowing BNB Beacon Chain address... So some conversion takes place in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's impossible, since generating address from private keys involves irreversible hashing algorithms.

But what I needed is bench23 buffer tool, which converts HEX<>Bench32

https://slowli.github.io/bech32-buffer/

BTC Address - Mainnet

Data - Tag - bnb

Data - Encoding - Bench32

This is what used in crosschain BSC -> BNB transfer for `receiver` field of `transferOut` function